# Can a statement be called a proposition only if the truth value can be tested?

Tags: logic

A statement can be called a proposition if it asserts something. Even if we don't know the truth value (yet) it's still a proposition.
I believe the following are propositions (correct me if I'm wrong):

- There's an alien colony in the Andromeda galaxy
- X = 5, where X is an even prime
- X is an integer of 7 digits

I think this sentence isn't a proposition:

- X = 4

So, a proposition is something to which we can assert a truth value. If an algorithm can be constructed for testing the truth value and the search space is finite, a statement is regarded as a proposition. X=4 isn't a proposition because there are infinite numbers out there; the search space is infinite.

Comment: Mathematical logic concerns only mathematical propositions, which would exclude your first sentence. Also, variables in propositions that have a truth value need to be quantified ("There exists X ∈ S such that ...", or "For all X ∈ S, ...", where S is some set), unlike your X in sentence 2 and sentence 3. Lastly: The idea of testing a proposition is very interesting, but it needs to be made precise.

Comment: A proposition doesn't necessarily have to have an algorithm to decide its truth value.  You're thinking of a [decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)) proposition.

Comment: @DanAsimov If that’s true then ‘Mathematical Logic’ is pretty impoverished. Sure, it would be hard to state the sentence in question in PA or ZFC, but it’s clearly expressible in first-order language.

Comment: 'X = 4' is not a proposition in many computer languages.  It's an instruction or command to set 'X' to '4'.

I do believe it easy to imagine some author writing "Let X = (2+Y)", and Y turning out to equal 2.  In which case 'X = 4' is a proposition.